# ¿Como hacer que lo que hay en un cuadro de texto se envié a otro? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la primera ventana con un cuadro de texto de solo lectura y cuando se le da click al botón se crea otra ventana con otro cuadro de texto.

El caso es que yo quiero que lo que se introduzca en el cuadro de texto de la segunda ventana me lo muestre en el cuadro de texto de la primera ventana.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Ejericio comunicacion entre ventanas</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function abrirVentana(){
   var nuevaVentana = window.open("","");
   nuevaVentana.document.write("<div>Introduce nombre:<input type='text' id='nuevoNombre' name='nuevoNombre'><br><input type='button' value='Aceptar' onclick='window.close()'></div>");

   var valor = document.getElementById('nuevoNombre').value;
 
   document.getElementById('nombre').innertHTML = valor;
   
  }
 </script>
<div class="inicial">
  Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" readonly id="nombre">
  <input type="button" name="enviar" value="Enviar" onclick="abrirVentana()">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu código tenías un error, cuando vas a asignar valores a un `input` debes usar `.value` no `.innerHTML` por que el `input` es un elemento de entrada de texto, ahora en cuanto a tu solicitud para enviar valores de una ventana a otra podrías usar lo siguiente:

```js
function abrirVentana(){
    var nuevaVentana = window.open("","");
    nuevaVentana.document.write("<div>Introduce nombre:<input type='text' id='nuevoNombre' name='nuevoNombre'><br><input type='button' value='Aceptar' onclick='window.opener.capturarValor(document.getElementById(" + '"nuevoNombre"' + ").value); window.close();'></div>");
}

function capturarValor(nombre){
    document.getElementById('nombre').value = nombre;
}
```

```html
<div class="inicial">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" readonly id="nombre">
    <input type="button" name="enviar" value="Enviar" onclick="abrirVentana()">
</div>
```

Debes ejecutarlo en un entorno local ya que el snippet de código de SOes no permite abrir ventanas emergentes.

Answer (score 3):

Desde una ventana hija puedes hacer referencia directamente a funciones o variables de la página padre, por ejemplo:

```
//en la página padre: 
<script> 
function recibir_Parametros(valor){ 
..... 
} 
... 
</script>
```

y

```
//en la página hija:
 <script> 
    function informarPadreYSalir(valor){ 
        window.opener.recibir_Parametros(valor); 
        window.close(); 
    } 
    </script>
```